# Google maps api passing key=notsupplied

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-2

We have a issue where google maps is not working for our website.  The code is something like below:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=<c:out value='${mapsApiKey}'/>",
    dataType: "script",
    success: function () {
    google.load("maps", "2", {callback: function () {
        doStuff();
     }
}
```

When the google.load("maps", "2" runs a request is generated without the api key:

/maps?file=googleapi&key=notsupplied&v=2&callback=google.loader.callbacks.maps&async=2

It is meant to create a request with the apikey in it, instead it is putting notsupplied.

Any help on why the key isn't added to the request would be great.

Comment: FYI: The error was caused by placing two jsapi script includes on the page.  One which contained the key we were using and another which didn't supply a key.  The script which loads first wins, so if the jsapi with no key loads first then no key is supplied when loading google maps or other components.  The real solution was to only include jsapi once, and with the api key

Comment: I've got a similar problem, but with GWT. I am pretty confident that I'm not loading the same script twice, unless ``Maps.loadMapsApi()`` does that. I know that I am passing in the correct key.

Comment: You can use firebug to check if you are loading the script more than once.